# Load Dataframe to tables with relationship

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am studying pySpark. Appreciate your help. I have a dataframe

```
test={}
test["1"]={"id":"1","name":"A","vars":["x1","x2"]}
test["2"]={"id":"2","name":"B","vars":["x2"]}
test["3"]={"id":"3","name":"C","vars":["x3"]}
test["4"]={"id":"4","name":"D","vars":["x2","x3"]}
pdDF = DataFrame(test).transpose()
sparkDF=spark.createDataFrame(pdDF) 


+---+----+--------+
| id|name|    vars|
+---+----+--------+
|  1|   A|[x1, x2]|
|  2|   B|    [x2]|
|  3|   C|    [x3]|
|  4|   D|[x2, x3]|
+---+----+--------+
```

I need to load this dataframe using pyspark to database tables with the relationship One to Many

The Result should be:

```
Table (Entity)
    +---+----+
    | id|name|
    +---+----+
    |  1|   A|
    |  2|   B|
    |  3|   C|
    |  4|   D|
    +---+----+
Table(Link Table)

+---------+------+
|id_entity|id_var|
+---------+------+
|        1|     1|
|        1|     2|
|        2|     2|
|        3|     3|
|        4|     2|
|        4|     3|
+---------+------+

Table(Vars)

+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
|  1|  x1|
|  2|  x2|
|  3|  x3|
|  4|  x4|
+---+----+
```

Is it possible to do this?
And if it is possible how can I do this?
I read pySpark documentation, and cannot find something similar to this.
Thanks

Comment: I’m curious, in what context is this necessary?

Comment: It is the simple example, in my dataframe vars is the actors in the films dataframe and they have additional fields (age and etc.), so i decided to load this dataframe not in one table with the field actors. I think,it will be the best solution according to Relation therory of Databases

Comment: I meant why do you feel the _need_ to split the DataFrames in the first place, instead of just using a single one.

Comment: I am sorry, but i didn't catch you

Comment: should I rephrase my question?

Comment: Yes please, can you rephrase your question

Comment: Actually before I can answer that I have another question for you. Your post says “to database tables with the relationship One to Many.” Are you talking about a certain database, or do you just mean pandas DataFames? Also, i’m going to bed, so I will only be able to continue this tomorrow. Don’t worry though, I will return :)

Comment: I am talking about certain database (postgresql). Okay, I will wait, thank you very much for you help)

Comment: Aaah, you should have mentioned that before, it’s important information! Can you share more on the subject, about the database, etc?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL DB. And have three tables (mentioned in my questions above), their are linked by foreign keys:
Entity table-> Link table - has OneToMany relationship,
Vars table-> Link table - has OneToMany relationship

Comment: Was the answer by dumitru enough?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is how it goes with Scala, similar in Python:

Having this schema

```
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- vars: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

for this type of data

```
+---+----+--------+
| id|name|    vars|
+---+----+--------+
|  1|   A|[x1, x2]|
|  2|   B|    [x2]|
|  3|   C|    [x3]|
|  4|   D|[x2, x3]|
+---+----+--------+
```

you can explode on the array column "vars"

```
 val explodedDf = df.select(col("id"), col("name"), explode(col("vars")).as("var"))
```

and the dataframe will look like this:

```
| id|name|var|
+---+----+---+
|  1|   A| x1|
|  1|   A| x2|
|  2|   B| x2|
|  3|   C| x3|
|  4|   D| x2|
|  4|   D| x3|
+---+----+---+
```

Next will be collecting all posibibles values from "var" columns into and array called "vars"

```
  val varsWithPos = explodedDf.withColumn("vars",
    typedLit[Seq[String]](explodedDf.select(collect_set("var")).first().getAs[Seq[String]](0)))
    .select(col("id"), col("name"), col("var"), array_position(col("vars"), col("var")).as("pos"))
```

table entity ->

```
varsWithPos.select("id", "name").distinct().show()

+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
|  1|   A|
|  2|   B|
|  3|   C|
|  4|   D|
+---+----+
```

table link ->

```
varsWithPos.select("id", "pos").show()

+---+---+
| id|pos|
+---+---+
|  1|  1|
|  1|  3|
|  2|  3|
|  3|  2|
|  4|  3|
|  4|  2|
+---+---+
```

table vars ->

```
varsWithPos.select("var", "pos").distinct().show()

+---+---+
|var|pos|
+---+---+
| x1|  1|
| x3|  2|
| x2|  3|
+---+---+
```